# Create a webservice that keeps data secure?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, web-services, web-applications, server-side

I want to create a webservice that allows users to enter the longitude and latitude for a particular building.  Buildings will belong to a broader category called a Region.  If a specific building does not exist in a region the user could add the longitude and latitude data through the webservice.  Similarly if a user finds data to be inaccurate, they could update it.

This webservice would not need to have a web front-end only a RESTful API that would only be accessible to my application(s).  I want the webservice to be able to accept new and updated data (as described above) and also print out relevant data (in xml format) based on the appropriate API calls.

I need to ensure that this data would be secure - i.e. nobody would be able to gain access to the data i have accumulated.

What is the best way to do this?  I have familiar with client side Java and not much server side technology (not familiar with server-side Java, rails, django, etc...).  What language/frameworks should i use that would accomplish my needs with the shallowest learning curve?

Comment: would django work for this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have never programmed server-side code you will be facing a pretty steep learning curve, I'm afraid. If you are comfortable with Java then the Restlet framework mentioned by another commenter is a good choice. It is easy to use, includes both client and server tools, and has pretty decent documentation. The video screencasts are very good.

Another option is Ruby on Rails. I am currently implementing something very similar to what you are planning and Rails has worked extremely well. Rails has built-in support for XML output through both the ActiveRecord class and XML Builder templates. I used Atom Authentication (http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/17/dive.html) between the client and server and it is working beautifully. There is a learning curve for both Ruby and Rails but the power of the framework makes it worth it. I am partial to the Ruby and Rails books at The Pragmatic Programmer but O'Reilly has some good ones, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use basic authentication (username/pw) with ssl enabled.  That way you are encrypting the connection and providing a broadly supported means of authentication.  I believe apache Axis will take care of most of it for you.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Comment: Not the old, abandoned, buggy Axis 1, though!  Use Axis 2 (an entirely new code base), or Apache CXF, or Glassfish Metro.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) framework to deploy web services that are password protected.  It supports basic authentification and several others out of the box.  You can also set up your services behind an https "server connector".

Another approach is to run your application in a Java EE application server which supports JSR 196 (eg, Glassfish or JBoss).  You would then use the server's facilities to establish the authentication.

Here is the [Glassfish security page](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/security/).